# Is it OK to overload ShowDialog() so that a child form returns information as an out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In an earlier question about [how to return a string from a dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form), **yapiskan** suggested [overloading the child form's ShowDialog() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form#280731) to include an out parameter.

My question is whether or not this is a good approach in C#.

Here is some example code, based on yapiskan's suggestion.  In the child form (in this example, it's a form with a textbox on it), you just need to add the ShowDialog overload and assign UI values to the out parameter:

```
public DialogResult ShowDialog(out string s)
{
    DialogResult result = this.ShowDialog();
    s = this.textBox1.Text;
    return result;
}
```

And to show the form and retrieve the entered text, you do this:

```
using (CustomDialog frm = new CustomDialog())
{
    string s;
    if (frm.ShowDialog(out s) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do something with s
    }
}
```

One advantage I can think of is that this approach forces the user of the CustomDialog form to get the information it contains through the form's ShowDialog method (rather than from a who-knows-what-it's-called method like GetMyData() or something).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better to have a Public property/method and get the information.

What would you do if you would need 3..4..5 informations, having 5 parameters out? More clean to have accessors to get your information from the Dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure. With parameters on the dialog, you can't ensure that the user is aware of what info is available (e.g. he might miss the GetFullName() method and write his own instead). With everything in one ShowDialog overload, he can't miss it.

Comment: to clarify: he might write his own by combining the dialog's GetFirstName and GetLastName methods.

Comment: If he needs it, he will get the accessor to get the information. He might just not always need to information. In that case he will be fine with accessor. Otherwise, with out, he might do not need the string but would have to create a variable... for nothing...

Comment: An advantage of getting all the info from one method (either a ShowDialog overload or GetData or something) is that if you add a parameter any calling classes have to be modified to be aware of it, in order to compile.

Comment: The other point is that use of properties is the established pattern here and one that works well - not least because (as above) there may be no "out" to return if the user has cancelled.

Comment: @Murph: in the code example, there would be an out no matter how the dialog was closed. It might not be meaningful, but that's what the check for DialogResult.OK is for.

Comment: Maybe this should be a posted question, but: if you use the properties pattern and you add a new property, is there a way to require the users of the dialog to handle the new property in some way at compile time? I'm sorry if I'm not phrasing this clearly.

Comment: I heartily agree with the public property approach. I had asked a similar question a little while back and this route worked perfectly, plus it makes it highly reusable

Comment: Wow. Time goes by and now I completely agree with you. I read this and thought "what kind of an idiot would make consumers of his class declare a bunch of parameters instead of just reading properties?" This might be the dumbest thing my past self ever wrote.

Answer (score 5):

It should not be OK since .net framework does not use this design. In the case of OpenFileDialog class, it has a parameterless ShowDialog() method returning a DialogResult. Once this method called, user is supposed to get the selected files by using the FileName, FileNames, SafeFileName and SafeFileNames methods.

Let's assume that this implented in the "out parameter" way. I would have to write code like this just to get the SafeFileName:

```
string dummyFileName;
string[] dummyFileNames;
string safeFileName;
string[] dummySafeFileNames;

myDialog.ShowDialog(out dummyFileName, out dummyFileNames, out safeFileName, out dummySafeFileNames);
```

Comment: I can't argue with that. This does look awful.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I try to avoid out parameters wherever possible, although I understand that like GoTo they are sometimes a necessary evil. I would say that it would be much better to use properties or methods to return the information.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a custom modal dialog that collects only one piece of information is a pretty extreme outlier.  Much more common are zero and many.

And a dialog that collects many pieces of data is almost certain to be modified at some point to collect just one more.  I'd much rather fix only the code that uses that one new piece of data than every single piece of code that uses the modified dialog.

Also, think about how a developer uses IntelliSense to use your class.  He's going to type this:

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
d.ShowDialog(
```

...and at that last keystroke, IntelliSense will pop up telling him that he now has to declare three new string variables to hold the out parameters.  So he moves the cursor up, and starts typing:

```
string foo;
string
```

...and, what was the name of the second parameter again?  So it's back down to the open paren, hit CTRL+SPACE, oh yeah, it's `bar`, back up to the previous line, etc.

The problem with using properties on a custom dialog is that the Form class already has a million properties, and the three or four special ones that you're creating are going to get lost in the mix.  To fix this, create a class for the dialog parameters and a `Parameters` property of that type on the custom dialog.  That makes code like this easy to write:

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
d.Parameters.Foo = "foo";
d.Parameters.Bar = "bar";
d.Parameters.Baz = "baz";
```

because the parameter names pop up in IntelliSense, and you don't need to declare any variables to hold their values.

Comment: All good points, thanks. One of the reasons I like C# (I started with VB3) and OOP in general is that I can change something and then rely on the language and the IDE to force me to deal with that change throughout the program. The multiple properties approach doesn't give me that.

Comment: The Intellisense and having to declare one or more variables before calling ShowDialog are sufficiently a problem that I probably wouldn't do this at work. I was hoping that one of the answers to my question would be some way of declaring the parameters in-line.

Comment: For a second there I thought that I could return a custom Parameters object instead of a string in my example, and that way I would only have to declare one variable before calling ShowDialog. But the callers would then happily ignore any newly-added fields.

Comment: So I guess the declaration of each parameter is unavoidable, given the advantage I'm claiming for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is typically to write a method that internally calls ShowDialog, then formats the output data appropriately. For (contrived) example:

```
public string GetFolderName(){
    if(this.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        return this.FolderName.Text;
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

In most cases I make this method static, and instantiate the dialog itself from within the body of the method - that way the caller doesn't have to deal with form references, or the notion of having to chose which 'show' method to call.

In the non-edge cases of having multiple output values, I typically construct a struct that holds these values, then have my 'Get' function return that struct.

```
public struct FolderData {
    public static FolderData Empty = new FolderData();

    public string FolderName {get; set;}
    public int FilesInFolder {get; set;}
}

public FolderData GetFolderData(){
    if(this.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        return new FolderData {
            FolderName = this.FolderName.Text;
            FilesInFolder = int.Parse(this.FilesInFolder.Text);
        }
    }
    return FolderData.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this one because I don't like the approach of getting result from a property or a method after you have done with the class. After dialog form was shown and closed I think the object should not be used any more because logically you have done with the dialog then why should I use its property or method to get the result?

Comment: Well if you see the using(...) either with out or property it still in memory after the if so you can use it. So your last sentence is fine but not with the example of the question.

Comment: It could be in the memory that's not the problem. I'm in the logic of this and by that I think; either it is in the memory, it is nice to not to be used.

Comment: You're not logically done with the dialog.  It's just no longer displayed on the screen.

Comment: You deserve the check for starting all this.  :)

Comment: As the other Robert indicates, the dialog isn't gone, just hidden. I wouldn't call using an out parameter in this case a 'best-practice' since nobody else advocates it or thinks it's a good idea.

Comment: But can you tell me a case that you will show, close, and show the dialog again programmatically and that's not a design issue?

Comment: I don't understand your objection to querying the dialog after it has hidden itself (it's not gone). I think you need to elaborate why you think it's an issue with some code that illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Musigenesis, you really don't want to force client code to break when you change your dialog, and using an out parameter that is only sometimes valid isn't a good design. As @Daok says, when you have more than 1 value returned this starts to get messy and ugly fast.

You also can't force client code to use the result any more than the .net framework ensures that you call properties on a file dialog. You're also not forcing the caller to do anything with the out parameter, all you've forced them to do is to accept a variable that they may not want to use.

If the dialog is very generic this may not be applicable, but instead of chucking all sorts of properties to the dialog itself, have a single method that you use consistently throughout your application, and have that return a specific class that holds the relevant data.

```
public sealed class MySaveDialogResult
{
    public static MySaveDialogResult NonOkResult(); // Null Object pattern
    public MySaveDialogResult( string filePath ) { ... }

    // encapsulate the dialog result
    public DialogResult DialogResult { get; private set; } 
    // some property that was set in the dialog
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    // another property set in the dialog
    public bool AllowOVerwrite { get; private set; }
}
```

and your dialog is

```
public MySaveDialog ...
{
    public MySaveDialogResult GetDialogResult() { .... }
}
```

The essence is a small immutable utility class that also implements null object pattern. The null object is returned whenever the dialog result wasn't OK. Obviously the above is a shot in the dark for your needs, so alter it at will, make inheritance hierarchies, etc.

The main point is to have `GetDialogResult()`, a single method on the dialog, to returned a class that encapsulates all the relevant dialog data.

---

edit:

@yapiskan wonders why not just 'out' the `MyDialogResult` versus calling `GetDialogResult()`.

IMO - The points are simply:

1. That's not the convention
2. A method call is trivially easy, and made easier when you follow the 'convention' argument as made above.
3. `out` is awkward to use. `GetDialogResult()` is not forcing the caller to write awkward code, and it doesn't force the user to consume the dialog result at the point of invoking the dialog.
4. *Normally* the dialog isn't re-instantiated or re-shown to get the result, it's already there. Show() and Hide() do just that.

The reality is you're trading a method call for an awkward ShowDialog() syntax. Method calls are cheap, and you can't guarantee the caller will use your out parameter any more than you can guarantee they will call GetDialogResult(). So why bother. Make the thing easy to use, or don't overload ShowDialog in the first place.

Maybe whatever you're sub-classing is funky and acts differently and it's not applicable to your situation, but general design is forms don't go away when you click OK, they go away when they are Disposed() of.

Comment: All good points, thanks. I agree completely with the last point, that I want a single method on the dialog that returns all the relevant data. I mostly work alone and normally I would add a GetData() method or whatever to the dialog and use that with no problem.  {more ...}

Comment: But working in a group recently, I've become more aware of the problem of adding stuff to classes and forms that the other developers never realize is there. The idea of merging the GetData approach with a ShowDialog overload appealed to me because other developers would have to interact with ...

Comment: ... the dialog that way (since there would be no other way of getting at its internal data). I don't know. It's hard to stay excited about an idea when everyone else hates it.  :)

Comment: Well, in all honesty, forcing code to break just pisses people off. It's better to send emails, etc. You can only encourage people. At least with a single data collection method that gets all relevant dialog data there is less likelihood of them missing the trees for the forest.

Comment: The idiom is to create conventions and follow them. It's in the same vein as Spolsky's 'Making Wrong Code Look Wrong'. When you follow conventions you make it easier to program against them. This doesn't happen all at once, but happens in code reviews and discussions.

Comment: I just wonder if you think of an encapsulated class like "MySaveDialogResult" and there is a method that returns the result "MySaveDialogResult" why don't you think to combine them in a ShowDialog method that gets an out parameter typed as "MySaveDialogResult" instead of...

Comment: ... calling two different methods like ShowDialog and GetMySaveDialogResult to get a result?

Comment: "Method calls are cheap, and you can't guarantee the caller will use your out parameter any more than you can guarantee they will call GetDialogResult()". That's surely right but I just cannot accept the logic of loading a class by a method and get the result by another one. But...

Comment: ...as @buyutec mentioned, in .Net Framework things are gone like that.

Comment: Surely, but the question was tagged 'best-practices' so while we can agree to disagree as a matter of style, and you're free to write the code you like to write, the 'best-practice' is to follow convention :)