# How to carry text values over to a text box on another form?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to carry the value of a single textbox into another textbox on another form.

In form 1 i have the following code:

```
private SecondForm secondForm;
public void SecondFormTextBox()
{
    uname.Text = secondForm.uname.Text;
}
```

In form 2 I have the following code.

```
public TextBox uname
{
    get
    {
        return uname;
    }
}
```

I recieve the following errors, hope you can help!!

> An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.AdministratorHome.uname.get'
>
> Ambiguity between
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.AdministratorHome.uname'
>   and
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.AdministratorHome.uname'

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# beginner help, How do I pass a value from a child back to the parent form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form)

Comment: Within the call to uname (which is a property method), you're returning the value of the same property, is kinda recursive so It won't compile.

Comment: Instead of declaring private SecondForm secondForm; declare it as Public

Comment: I think you will need to show us a bit more code. That error likely means you treating a class name like a variable and trying to make a static call and not an instance call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets do an exampe with passing a value from textBox on form1 on button press, to a textBox on form2.
Code:

```
//form1:
Form2 form2;

private void button1_Click()
{
   if(form2 == null)
   {
       form2 = new Form2();
       form2.Show(); 
   }
   form2.PassToForm2(textBox1.Text);
}

//form2:
private void PassToForm2(string msg)
{
   textBox1.Text = msg;
}
```

Hope it helps,
Mitja

Answer (score 1):

In the above code snippet, the property get is referencing itself; that's a *bad idea*(tm). If you want to get the text value, you would have some kind of property like so:

```
public string TextBoxText
{
   get { return myTextBox.Text; } // myTextBox is the symbol for your text box
}
```

Then the other form can simple access that text via the property. Next up, in your first code snippet, you haven't assigned an instance to your second form variable; it's null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `TextBox uname` doesn't have setter - or at least you haven't pasted it.

Second, do you set `secondForm` property in `Form1` to the instance of `Form2` (for example in the constructor)?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided, it does not look like you are creating an instance to the secondForm. If you are doing so, can you please provide more code.