# How to modify datatable from another winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have 2 forms.  Form1 contains a datatable.  When I instantiate form2, I pass it one record from form1's datatable.  Then I do some things in form2, and now I want to update the datatable in Form1, based on what was done in form2.

How can I accomplish this?  I need to remove datarows, and add new datarows, and I must have the data from form2 to accomplish this.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-sharp-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-for) for example. I did [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+value+back+form) on SO.

Comment: @Otiel -Ok, I get that part.  Here's where I'm stuck: I'm done manipulating the data on form2, how do I tell form1 to come pick up the data before I close form2?

Comment: Do you use `form2.Show()` or `form2.ShowDialog()`? Isn't the `string result = formOptions.GetMyResult;` line from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-sharp-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-for/280586#280586) satisfying for you?

Comment: @Otiel -I use Show(), how would ShowDialog() help?  I still don't understand.

Comment: By using `ShowDialog()`, you'll make your `form2` modal and the run will be waiting on the `form2.ShowDialog()` line to continue. The solution is then simply to add `string result = formOptions.GetMyResult;` just after the `form2.ShowDialog()` line.

Comment: @Otiel -If I can send any datatype through that way, then perfect.  YOu should post your last comment as an answer.

Comment: I'd rather think you should delete your question if you got the solution now. It is likely a mod will close it as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/c-sharp-beginner-help-how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-for):

- Create a public property in `form2`:

  ```
  public partial class Form2 : Form {

      private DataTable data;

      public DataTable Data {
          get { return data; }
      }
  }
  ```
- And access it in `form1` when you're done with `form2`:

  ```
  //...
  form2.ShowDialog();
  // Retrieved modified dataTable
  dataTable = form2.Data;
  //...
  ```