# Checkboxes in groupbox automatically uncheck when closing form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, groupbox

I have a `GroupBox` in a `Form`. In this `GroupBox` I have three `Checkboxes` that can be checked either one, two or three. I want the checked state to maintain after I close this form and reopen it. Is it something about the `GroupBox` that has to be taken into consideration? How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide some code we can help you better. How do open the form and how do you close it?

Comment: [this link can probably help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by closing the form? Closing a single form and reopen it while the application remains alive or closing the whole application?

Comment: If retention on a form is the concern, a static list from a class should help you out, if retention even the application is closed is the concern, database should help you out.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280586/2523942). It may help

Comment: @Andreea . You should select an answer if one of them solves this problem for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class from the groupbox items. Add properties for each item, i.e. `.checked`

Store your object in a global variable. Before the form closes, update your global variable witht he current item structure and their checked properties.

On re-open of the form, load and prepare the groupbox from the custom object.

If your groupbox state needs to persist on application close, you will have to do the above, but use a database instead of a global variable.