# Pass value I have tried everything

Tags: c#

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm(string Username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Hey I tried to pass data from `form1` to `Mainform` and all the time that show me this error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'Username' of 'MainForm.MainForm(string)'

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: It's saying that you're not passing a string in when you call the `MainForm` constructor.  If the method signature says it takes a string, then you have to provide one when you call it.

Comment: How are you calling the MainForm?

Comment: You say you've tried everything. What have you tried? All you have shown us is the constructor of `MainForm`. How is this actually called, what have you tried when calling the constructor?

Comment: Duplicate of - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form)

Answer (score 3):

You have done at least one step, but you probably missed some.

You passed in the variable, but you didn't assign it yet:

```
public MainForm(string username)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Username = username;
}

public string Username { get; set; }
```

Here I have create a property named `Username` to assign the incoming variable to. (Note that I renamed your argument to make it lower-case, since that is how the naming convention is)

And you should provide a value when you call the `MainForm` constructor:

```
MainForm m = new MainForm("my name");
m.Show();
```

Comment: `   public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm(string Username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.username = Username;
        }

        public string username { get; set; }
` 
like that?

Comment: Yes, but your naming convention for properties and fields is the other way around, see my answer.

Comment: wasnt work.
and the argument is Username in Form1.

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Username' of 'MainForm.MainForm(string)'