# How to pass the value from child form to parent form?

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 forms called **BillingForm**(parent form) and **SearchProduct**(child form).

BillingForm code

```
private void textBoxProductNo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.F9)
    {
        using(SearchProduct sp=new SearchProduct)
        {
            sp.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}

public void updatedText(string fromChildForm)
{
     textBoxProduct.text=fromChildForm;
}
```

SearchProduct form code (Child Form)

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
    {
        BillingForm bf=(BillingForm)this.Owner;   //Error appear here 
        bf.updatedText("Hello World");
        this.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error message.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in BillingSoftware.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'BillingForm.MDIParent' to type 'BillingForm.BillingForm**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a value from a child back to the parent form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form)

Comment: @itsme86 I saw that coding. I used the same coding only. But I am getting Exception. Please look at my error message

Comment: Is BillingForm an MDI form?

Comment: @itsme86 MDIParent is MDI form..  BillingForm is one of child form of MDI form. When press ctrl+N in MDI form then BillingForm will be opened

Comment: From the code and error message, it appears that the `textBoxProductNo` control belongs to `BillingForm.MDIParent`, not `BillingForm.BillingForm`. Is that the case?

Comment: You can try something like `BillingForm bf = Application.OpenForms.OfType<BillingForm>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @RufusL No. textBoxProductNo control belongs to BillingForm, not to MDIParent Form.  MDIParent form contains menu name called File->new(BillingForm)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `BillingForm bf=(BillingForm)this.Owner;` and debug. When the code breaks, highlight your mouse over `Owner` and see what its type is. From there, see if there are any properties on `Owner` which will return the `BillingForm` that you are looking for.

Comment: @Slai Thank you for your code. It's working perfectly. Can you explain me that why my code shows error?. Thank you my friend

Comment: @Faisal because BillingForm is not the the owner :] maybe `BillingForm bf = this.MDIParent as BillingForm;` is ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the parent into constructor and use it in a variable

```
using(SearchProduct sp = new SearchProduct(this))
{
    sp.ShowDialog(this);
}

//In SearchProduct class
public BillingForm MyParent {get; private set;}

public SearchProduct(BillingForm parent)
{
    this.MyParent = parent;
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        BillingForm bf = this.MyParent;
        bf.updatedText("Hello World");
        this.close();
    }
}
```