# How to refresh a datagrid on a parent form, from a child form

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, refresh, parent-child

on frmBrand**s** there a dgBrands that gets it's data in subLoadDgBrands. on frm**Brand** you can add a record to the dtBrands when you fire the btnSave_Click eventhandler. that same event handler also calls frmBrand**s**.subLoadDgBrands however it does not refresh the dg that is displayed. I need it to refresh the dg on frmBrand**s** when you finish the save procedure on frm**Brand**, as i only want to refresh if the save was succesfull, and for a different form i need to pass back an integer to that sub

Here's the relevant code

````
    ```VB
        Public Class frmBrands
        
           Friend Sub subLoadDgBrands()
        
                dtBrands = fnGetBrand(0) 'Go get the data for the DataGridView
                dgBrands.DataBindings.Clear()
                dgBrands.DataSource = Nothing
                dgBrands.Rows.Clear()
                dgBrands.Columns.Clear()
        
                If dtBrands IsNot Nothing Then
                    dgBrands.DataSource = dtBrands
                    dgBrands.Refresh()
                    subFormatDgBrands()
                End If
            End Sub
        End Class
```
````

This event handler needs to refresh the datagrid on the instance of frmBrand**s** that this form was opened through

````
    ```VB
      Public Class frmBrand
        
           Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
             
                'intID is passed by parent form = intBrand_ID
                'intSupplier_ID is declared at the top of the form and set correctly by event handler
                Dim intResult As Integer = 0 
                Dim strMessage As String = ""
                Dim strBrandName As String = txtBrand.Text
        
                'string builder that checks if the important fields are filled in
                If strBrandName = "" Then 'if there is nothing written in str
                    If strMessage = "" Then 'and if the error message is empty
                        strMessage = "Please provide a brand name" 'then add the error message to the string
                    Else 'if the error message isn't empty '
                        strMessage &= "and brand name" 'then add str to the message
                    End If
                End If
        
                If intSupplier_ID < 1 Then 'if there is a 0 or negative ID selected, can also use cboSupplier.selectedValue
                    If strMessage = "" Then 'and if the error message is empty
                        strMessage = "Please provide a supplier" 'then add the error message to the string
                    Else 'if the error message isn't empty
                        strMessage &= "and supplier" 'then add "Title" to the message
                    End If
                End If
        
                'save string checker 
                If strMessage <> "" Then 'if there is something in the message
                    MsgBox(strMessage) 'display it
        
                Else 'if there's nothing in the message
                    intResult = fnSaveBrand(intID,
                                            intSupplier_ID,
                                            strBrandName) 'We can save
        
                    'Additional logic loop that gives some feedback if it isn't saved
                    If intResult < 1 Then 'feedback number if the save wasn't succesfull
                        MsgBox("ID fault") 'Will let the user know it didn't save
                    Else 'the save was succesfull
                        **frmBrands.subLoadDgBrands()** 'Needs to refresh the datagrid on the instance of frmBrand**s** that this form was opened through
                        Me.Close() 'then it closes the form
                    End If
                End If
            End Sub
        End Class
```
````

Comment: A third form, frmSupplier has a nearly identical save procedure, after which I want to pass back an integer to its parent form frmBrand and refresh its cboSupplier and set the selectedValue to the integer passed so it selects the record you just added.

like this;
```VB
public class frmSupplier

Private Sub btnSave_Click

(Shortened to make it brief)

**frmBrand.subLoadCboSupplier(intResult)
  Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I cannot get this to work and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect the changes even `frmBrand` is still open, make `subLoadDgBrands` as Public then after your insert query was executed, add this

```
Dim _frmBrands As frmBrands = TryCast(Me.Owner, frmBrands)
_frmBrands.subLoadDgBrands()
```

If you want to reflect the changes right after the `frmBrand` was close, then replace `Me.Close` with `Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`. Then in your code for opening `frmBrand` use

```
Using frmBrand As New frmBrand()
      frmBrand.ShowDialog(Me)
          
      If frmBrand.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
         subLoadDgBrands()
      End If

End Using
```

Comment: Yes the save works, I mean, the data I just added is there if I close and reopen the program. Why i dont just run the refresh sub under the formcall is because I want to run the refresh sub on its parent form only if the save was succesfull.
I want to use the same structure for a tertiary layer that also allows me to pass the refreshsub the integer that is returned from the save, so it can use it to set the combobox.selectedValue to it.

Comment: did you consider to use DialogResult? If the child form was closed with DialogResult = OK then refresh your datagridview.

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant for my situation.
I just want to trigger the frmBrandS.subLoadDgBrands from frmBrand, and optionally pass a variable as parameter. how do I do that?

Comment: Did you mean that you don't want to close the `frmBrand` but still the changes should reflect in `dgBrands`?

Comment: I already updated my answer, check if its work for you.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, thanks a lot!
After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form and using the c# to vb translator on telerik I tried this solution:
`Public class frmBrands
Private Sub subLoadfrmBrand(intID As Integer)
Dim frmBrand as New frmBrand
frmBrand.ShowDialog(Me) learned you can pass a handle to the instance parent here!
end sub
end class`
and
`public class frmBrand
Private sub btnSave_Click
Dim frmBrands as frmBrands = Me.Owner
frmBrands.subLoadDgBrands()
end sub
end class`
It worked!

Comment: Nice bro. Keep going.

Comment: I'll give your solution a try too. although I don't understand what the TryCast does, and how its different from just saying Dim frmBrands as frmBrands = me.owner. I read learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/… the documentation but it might as well be written in chinese haha. the rest in your solution made sense.