# Saving from one Winforms to another Winforms C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to save from one form to another. My main form has a save feature saving everything on that form, but I want to save the the winning hero from this form to the main form. Here is the code from the second form:

```
{
    // variables to be used in game
    private Hero[] heroes;
    private Villian[] villians;
    private Queue<int> TurnQueue;
    private Random random;
    private bool gameOngoing = true;
   // private Queue<int> villianTurnQueue;
    private int VillianHP;
    private string dir;  //creates a directory
    private string RPGbinaryFile; //creates a binary file in the C drive
    private Hero hero;
    public RPGForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        random = new Random();
        dir = @"C:\C#";
```

]            RPGbinaryFile = @"Binary.bin";
villians = new Villian[2];
villians[0] = new MonsterOne("RedMonster", 80, 10, lblVillianPoints, lblVillianName, pgbVillian, ptbxVillian);
villians[1] = new MonsterTwo("GreenMonster", 80, 10, lblVillianPoints2, lblVillianName2, pgbMonster2, ptbMonster2);
heroes = new Hero[2];
heroes[0] = new Figther("BlueFighter", 50, 20, lblHero1Points, lblHero1Name, pgbHero1, ptbHero1);
heroes[1] = new Mage("WhiteMage", 75, 10, lblHero2Points, lblHero2Name, pgbHero2, ptbHero2);

```
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //setup for Villian
        villians = new Villian[2];
        villians[0] = new MonsterOne("RedMonster", 80, 10, lblVillianPoints, lblVillianName, pgbVillian, ptbxVillian);
        villians[1] = new MonsterTwo("GreenMonster", 80, 10, lblVillianPoints2, lblVillianName2, pgbMonster2, ptbMonster2);

        //setup for Villian
        heroes = new Hero[2];
        heroes[0] = new Figther("BlueFighter", 50, 20, lblHero1Points, lblHero1Name, pgbHero1, ptbHero1);
        heroes[1] = new Mage("WhiteMage", 75, 10, lblHero2Points, lblHero2Name, pgbHero2, ptbHero2);

        TurnQueue = new Queue<int>();

        // set the turn queue
        SetupTurn();
    }


    // turn queue method for both heroes and villains
    private void SetupTurn()
    {
        //heroes turn
        for (int i = 0; i < heroes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (heroes[i].IsAlive())
            {
                TurnQueue.Enqueue(i);
            }
        }
        // villain turn
        for (int i = 0; i < villians.Length; i++)
        {
            if (villians[i].IsVillianAlive())
            {
                TurnQueue.Enqueue(i + heroes.Length);
            }
        }
    }


    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // track defeated heroes
      
        while (TurnQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            int currentTurn = TurnQueue.Dequeue();
            //int villianIndex = TurnQueue.Dequeue();              

            // get heroes to attack
            if (currentTurn < heroes.Length && currentTurn >= 0)
            { 
                // Hero's turn
                int damage = heroes[currentTurn].AttackDamage();

                // hit villian
                Random random = new Random();
                int target = random.Next(0, villians.Length);

                while (!villians[target].IsVillianAlive())
                {
                    target = random.Next(0, villians.Length);
                }
                // villain attack damage
                damage = villians[target].VillainTakeDamage(damage);

                // Print out attack logs
                txtOutput.Text = $"{heroes[currentTurn].GetName()} hit the {villians[target].GetVillianName()} for {damage}!\r\n{txtOutput.Text}";

                WeWon(); // we won method
            
            }
            else
            {
                // gets turn from villain 
                currentTurn = currentTurn - 2;
                // get villian's attack damage
                Random random = new Random();
                int damage = villians[currentTurn].VillianAttackDamage();
                int target = random.Next(0, heroes.Length);

                while (!heroes[target].IsAlive())
                {
                    target = random.Next(0, heroes.Length);
                }

                damage = heroes[target].TakeDamage(damage);

                //print out what happened in the log
                txtOutput.Text = $"{villians[currentTurn].GetVillianName()} hits {heroes[target].GetName()} for {damage}!\r\n{txtOutput.Text}";

                if (!heroes[0].IsAlive() && !heroes[1].IsAlive())
                {
                    TurnQueue.Clear(); // turn queue method
                    btnStart.Enabled = false; // disable start button
                    MessageBox.Show("The Villians defeated the heroes!", "We lost!");
                }
            }
        }
        SetupTurn(); // method of setup turns for heroes and villains
    }


    private void VillianWins() 
    {
        if (!heroes[0].IsAlive() && heroes[1].IsAlive())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We Lost to the Villian!", "We Lost!");
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            TurnQueue.Clear();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        }
    }

    private void WeWon()
    {
            if (!villians[0].IsVillianAlive() && !villians[1].IsVillianAlive())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The heroes defeated the big villian!!", "The Heroes Won");
                btnStart.Enabled = false; // disable start button
                TurnQueue.Clear(); // turn queue method
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // Dialog connected to MazeForm
                return;  
            }
        //}
    }

    // Reset button to restart game
    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Enable start button 
        btnStart.Enabled = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < villians.Length; i++)
        {
            // Check if the villain is not null and initialize them
            if (villians[i] != null)
            {
                // Set the initial HP values for villains
                villians[i].SetInitialValues(80);              
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < heroes.Length; i++)
        {
            // Check if the hero is not null and initialize them
            if (heroes[i] != null)
            {
                // Set the initial HP values for heroes
                heroes[i].SetInitialValues(85); 
            }
        }

        // Clear the textbox
        txtOutput.Text = " ";

        // clear turn queues
        TurnQueue.Clear();
        TurnQueue.Clear();

        // Set the game state to ongoing
        gameOngoing = true;

        // causes the Setup turn to start a fresh queue
        SetupTurn();
    }

}
```

}

Part of Main form

```
    private void SaveGameState()
    {
        try
        {
            //creates a director if one doesn't exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }

            // variables declared to be saved in the game
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtX.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(txtY.Text);
            string roominfo = txtOutput.Text;
            string selectedItem = cboBox.SelectedItem != null ? cboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() : string.Empty;

            using BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dir + binaryFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
            //writes data on one line in the text file and application
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(x); // saves x coordinates
                binaryWriter.Write(y);// saves y coordinates
                binaryWriter.Write(roominfo); //// saves output message 
                // Save the selected item from ComboBox
                binaryWriter.Write(selectedItem);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have access to this file.", "Access Denied");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error saving the game.", "Error");
        }
    }

    // creates a load/read from a binary file for the x and y coordinates

    private void LoadGameState()
    {
        try
        {
            //creates a director if one doesn't exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }
            if (File.Exists(dir + binaryFile))
            {
                using BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(dir + binaryFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

                while (binaryReader.PeekChar() != -1) // writes the last saved game state
                {
                    // variables declared to be written in the game
                    int x = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                    int y = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                    string roominfo = binaryReader.ReadString();
                    string selectedItem = binaryReader.ReadString();

                    // appear when the game loads to show the last saved state
                    txtX.Text = x.ToString();
                    txtY.Text = y.ToString();
                    txtOutput.Text = roominfo;


                    // select the item in the combo box if one was saved in the game
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem))
                    {
                        cboBox.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have access to this file.", "Access Denied");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The file doesn't exist.");
        }
    }

   
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveGameState();
        MessageBox.Show("Game saved successfully!", "Saved");
        //rpgForm.SaveGameState();
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGameState();
        MessageBox.Show("Game loaded successfully!", "Load");
        //rpgForm.LoadGameState();
    }
}
```

}

This is an assignment which is nearly complete, but my instructor added another save feature that's not in my textbook and I don't really know much about saving forms within forms. I just want to save the information of the hero that wins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a value from a child back to the parent form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form)

Comment: It's helpful but no. I actually added more code to my project as I am saving information from one form to the other. The main form has the saved information. I am expected to open that form and place the save information into that second form. It's not working out properly for me.

Comment: Ahh I see. In that case, you should just be able to pass the information to the constructor. Something like `var dialog = new RpgForm(heros)`, then you can store `heros` within `RpgForm`.

Comment: Use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to properly format your code.